# Foomen Email Attachment

Tags: magento2

currently i am using fooman extension for pdf attachment which is working fine now i want to add some more document upload by customer while placing order in magento2 fooman attach file using this abstract class AbstractObserver now i want add some function here how can i over ride this class  abstract class AbstractObserver.